# Is there a space $X$ such that $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $X \times X$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there a space $X$ such that $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $X \times X$?

If there is it would need to have fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$.

$\pi_1(X \times X)=\pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(X)$

What can I do now?

Comment: Observe that $\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be $G \times G$ for any $G$. This is quite easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a group $ G $ such that $ \mathbf Z \cong G \times G $?

Comment: Don't think so but how can I prove this formally?

Comment: @Walter When is $ G \times G $ cyclic?

Comment: Not sure, maybe gcd is 1?

Comment: The gcd of what and what?

Comment: Could you finish your answer please. i don't really understand the answer on the linked question